# Eclipse & C/C++ - do I need to install a compiler separately?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I'm starting to learn C, and installed the eclipse plugin for C/C++ development (the CDT plugin). I'm testing the setup with a hello world program, but it looks like the eclipse C plugin (CDT) doesn't have a compiler built in. I thought eclipse plugins were usually self-sufficient? Do I need to install a compiler separately to complete my c setup, or how do I get it to compile from within eclipse.

I did the usual: created a new c project in the eclipse workspace, created a new hello.c file that looks like this:

```
/*
 * hello.c
 *
 *  Created on: 2009-12-21
 *  Author: geek
 */

main(){
 printf("hello world\n");
}
```

**Edit: OS is windows Vista** 
Can someone suggest a compiler that's known to play nice with eclipse (or a tutorial that you've used yourself to get this sorted out)

Comment: What Operating System are you using? Do you have any other IDEs or development environments installed? You might already have a C/C++ compiler.

Comment: You are correct.  You need to have a compiler installed.

Comment: my OS is windows vista. So the eclipse CDT doesn't come with the compiler built in? I'm a little surprised

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X, you can install Xcode from your installation CD to get the gcc compiler, or in [Li|U]nix you probably already have gcc installed. If you're on Windows check out [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Thats a free C/C++ compiler based on gcc.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the easiest way to get started with C programming on Windows is to install the free [Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/). It comes with a compiler built-in, and unless you *really* want to use Eclipse for some reason, it's probably the least friction option.

Comment: +1 If you develop Windows then msvc (visual studio) is most wideley used.

Comment: Can this be used for Mac OSX as well?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a compiler installed separately. Here is a [CDT/compiler installation guide](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/) for different operating systems.